# Creating a previously null parent, with child object with Newtonsoft

Tags: json.net

Using NewtonsoftJson, and without knowing the entire 'model', how do you create a new parent object and set a child value, when the parent doesn't already exist?

**Existing parent**

```
//The parent already exists, but the child does not.     
jobj["Parent1"]["Child"] = true; 

File.WriteAllText(mypath, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(joj, Formatting.Indented));

//output
//Successfully creates new child
```

**New parent**

```
//The parent does not exist, nor the child. 
//Throws null reference exception as jobj["Parent3"] doesn't exist
jobj["Parent3"]["Child"] = true;

File.WriteAllText(mypath, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(joj, Formatting.Indented));
```

**JSON**

```
{
"parent1": {
   "child": true
},
"parent2": {
  "child": true
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to check whether the parent exists, and create it if it doesn't.

```
JToken parent = jobj["Parent3"];
if (parent == null)
{
    // parent object doesn't exist so create it
    parent = new JObject();
    jobj["Parent3"] = parent;
}
parent["Child"] = true;
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, an alternative to my approach. I think they're both useful, with the advantage of yours not needing to create a POCO to represent the object passed into the new JProperty constructor.

Answer (score 0):

To add a new JProperty you need to add use JToken.FromObject within the JProperty constructor.

eg

```
jobj.Add(new JProperty("parent3", JToken.FromObject(new Parent { Child = true})));
```